# How to extract several dataframes from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key

I currently trying to extract several dataframes from a dictionary. The problem is, that the number of dataframes will vary, sometimes I'll have two dataframes in there and sometimes 30.

At the beginning I create a dictionary (dict_of_exceptions) from a dataframe (exceptions_df). In this dictionary I'll have several dataframes depending on how many different 'Source Wells' I have. With the current code I can extract the first dataframe from the dictionary which is j:

```py
dict_of_exceptions = {k: v for k, v in exceptions_df.groupby('Source Well') }

print (dict_of_exceptions)

for k in dict_of_exceptions.keys(): 
    j = dict_of_exceptions[k]
```

Could someone help me modify the last line to go trough the dictionary and extract each dataframe (and name them like the corresponding key)?

Comment: Hi chrizzly and welcome to SO. Could you provide more details about what you would like to do ? and some data ?
Your loop is able to extract all the dataframes in your dictionnary, it's just that you're overwritting your variable `j` in each loop.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. I use .csv files as worklists to tell a pipetting robot how much volume he needs to pipette from well x to well y. If in well x is not enough liquid I'll get a exception file (as .csv). In this file it says from well x to well y: Transfer Volume 10, Actual Volume 5. From well x to well z: Transfer Volume 10, Actual Volume 0 and so on. To know how much liquid I need to refill I would like to write a code which extracts from the .csv file the information about how much volume was missing in well x to refill it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I'd like to better understand what you want to do in Python. E.g. : what are you going to do with your `j` variable ? Why do you have to affect these dataframes to new variables ? Can't you just work directly with the dictionnary ? Ex : `dict_of_exceptions["well x"] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your intention, but could not really read your intentions from your code though. Currently, as @cyrilb38 stated in comments, your loop is overriding j, so you would only be able to see the result of last iteration. Anyways, rather transforming use dataframe instead, and I think (may be wrong) that you call your row a dataframe. Replacing a groupby object with dict is not what you wanted, or it is just prolonging the process for nothing.

If you want to see the info of Well X only for example, try this

```
exceptions_df[exceptins_df['Source Well'] == 'Well X']
```